# What is the last level of Candy Crush Saga?

Tags: candy-crush-saga

Do Candy Crush Saga developers keep on increasing the levels or is there any last level?

I have reached 1800+ now(Feb 2017 to be precise)... and it does not seem to end.

Comment: While there physically has to be a definite last level at any one time, I doubt there will ever be an *actual* end in the foreseeable future. As long as people have money to spend, the devs will keep on periodically updating the app to add new levels.

Answer (score 7):

The developers add extra chapters every few weeks, every chapter has 15 extra levels.

As of June 3, 2015 the game has 980 "normal" levels and 665 "Dreamworld" levels. So the total is 1645 levels.

Also note that different versions of the game update at different intervals, so, for example, the Android version will sometimes have less levels than the iOS version.